# How can I turn off ActiveRecord's SQL query logging without also disabling my own debug output (logger.debug)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Most of the debug-level output that Rails generates during a request is just noise, which prevents me from seeing the actual debug output that I logged and *want* to see.

Example of logged SQL noise that I want to turn off:

```
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
```

Example of output I still want to see:

```
... Resetting user
```

I know I can completely silence ActiveRecord's logger with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

but that would prevent my own messages from my ActiveRecord models from being logged:

```
logger.debug "... Resetting user"
```

I also know that Rails's SQL is logged at the debug level and that I can set the [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) instance's `level` to a higher level to prevent debug messages from being logged:

```
User.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

but again, that would prevent ***my own*** debug-level messages from being logged.  So that option doesn't satisfy me either.

So my question is: Is there any clean way to silence **only** the SQL log messages that come from the ActiveRecord internals?

**Update**: It looks like these SQL log messages are coming from `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber#sql` <sub>(in `lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:21`)</sub>.

I guess I could monkey-patch that method and replace it with a no-op in an initializer or something, but surely there's a better way...?

Is there a way to unsubscribe a log subscriber (or all subscribers) from ActiveRecord's list of subscribers?  How??